# I get an error when using Pyrogram with Threading in Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, customtkinter, pyrogram

Error Code;

[image]

I press the send message key, everything works normally, I press the stop key, again normal, but app.stop does not stop, I get an error when sending a message again

Code;

```
from customtkinter import *
import customtkinter as ctk
from threading import Thread
import time, os, asyncio
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.enums import MessageMediaType

run = True
path = os.getcwd()
app = Client(path + "\\users\\" + "user")
async def tg_bot():
    global run
    global app  # Reference the global app variable
    s = 0
    await app.start()
    async for ii in app.get_chat_history(-1002070231241):
        if ii.media == MessageMediaType.VIDEO:
            if run:
                s = s + 1
                await app.copy_message(-1002142940185, -1002070231241, ii.id, caption="")
                print(s, "sended.")
                await asyncio.sleep(1)

    await app.stop()

def start():
    global run
    run = True

    def don(dongu, _e):
        try:
            dongu.run_until_complete(tg_bot())
        finally:
            dongu.close()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event = asyncio.Event()
    oto = Thread(target=don, args=(loop, event))
    oto.daemon = True
    oto.start()

def stop():
    global run
    run = False
    global app
    app.stop

root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry("300x300")
basla = CTkButton(root, text="message send", command=start)
basla.place(x=75, y=100)

dur = CTkButton(root, text="stop", command=stop)

dur.place(x=75, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

Video;

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tTuNKZ_WR9KK7WOjXbdzP3-M_TC4l6yk/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Re, "I get an error when sending a message again" You'll be more likely to get help if you add the text of the error message to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to add parentheses in the app.stop call on line 46.

```
app.stop
```

You can just add parentheses:

```
app.stop()
```

The full code is now:

```
from customtkinter import *
import customtkinter as ctk
from threading import Thread
import time, os, asyncio
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.enums import MessageMediaType

run = True
path = os.getcwd()
app = Client(path + "\\users\\" + "user")
async def tg_bot():
    global run
    global app  # Reference the global app variable
    s = 0
    await app.start()
    async for ii in app.get_chat_history(-1002070231241):
        if ii.media == MessageMediaType.VIDEO:
            if run:
                s = s + 1
                await app.copy_message(-1002142940185, -1002070231241, ii.id, caption="")
                print(s, "sended.")
                await asyncio.sleep(1)

    await app.stop()

def start():
    global run
    run = True

    def don(dongu, _e):
        try:
            dongu.run_until_complete(tg_bot())
        finally:
            dongu.close()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event = asyncio.Event()
    oto = Thread(target=don, args=(loop, event))
    oto.daemon = True
    oto.start()

def stop():
    global run
    run = False
    global app
    app.stop()

root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry("300x300")
basla = CTkButton(root, text="message send", command=start)
basla.place(x=75, y=100)

dur = CTkButton(root, text="stop", command=stop)

dur.place(x=75, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope i helped you, have a nice day

Comment: mate how did I not think of that 

not working bro


c:\Users\Aev\Desktop\Projeler\Aevgram\test.py:46: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Stop.stop' was never awaited
  app.stop()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: Oh, sorry for that.
I can't manage to understand where the error is coming from.
I think it might be because you can not pass a coroutine to the run_until_complete method but I am not sure.